# OSX 10.7.3 Breaks freetds

Tags: macos, freetds

Being new to the Mac, and being an idiot,  I blindly upgraded my Mac from 10.7.2 to to 10.7.3.  Now my freetds connection to SQLServer has stopped working, i.e:

```
Error 20017 (severity 9):
Unexpected EOF from the server
OS error 36, "Operation now in progress"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server.
```

tsql -C shows:

```
                        Version: freetds v0.91
         freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: no
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 5.0
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: no
```

It worked like a champ until I upgraded to 10.7.3 (man what a mistake!)

Anybody have a clue where to start?  I guess the first question is where does freetds write a log file,  I didn't make any changes regarding the log file during installation,  so where is the default?

Comment: 10.7.3 is not "Snow Leopard". Oh, and what did you upgrade **from**? If it was from Snow Leopard, it's a major update and yes, you should have been a little bit more careful.

Comment: Changed the Title.  I Upgraded from 10.7.2 to 10.7.3

Comment: I got TSQL to connect by changing the TDS VERSION in freetds.conf to 7.0,  but now when I do connect, i.e. tsql -H host -U user -P password,  the sql prompt seems to ignore any command typed.  No matter what I type,  the prompt returns and the commands seem to be completely ignored!  The only thing it seems to respond to is exit!

Comment: Just rebuilt freetds-0.91,  same problem,  tsql just ignores all commands entered at the prompt!

Comment: just tried freetds-0.92.dev.10120124,  same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's working now. I just installed the 10.7.3 combo upgrade over the 10.7.3 simpleton upgrade. I did:

```
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

and it works.

I did this with freetds-.92dev012412, but I have a feeling the same solution will work with the stable .92.

Comment: I can confirm that the stable freetds-0.92 version from homebrew now works after applying the 10.7.3 combo upgrade over the Software Update version of the upgrade. I'm glad I found this thread!